# Not able to set data-id after AJAX success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, custom-data-attribute

I currently have a jQuery function where I perform an AJAX request. Upon success I see that the returned data is correct but when I try and change the `data-id="new"` to the new response, it does absolutely nothing.

I am loading the `data-id="new"` div into the DOM after initial page load.

I am able to navigate all the way to `.each-requirement` and change the HTML within with the response but unable to change the `.each-requirement` data-id.

HTML:

```
<div class="dashboard-container-toolbar dashboard-requirement-toolbar center">
<div class="select2-container requirements-select select2-allowclear" id="s2id_add-essential-requirement">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return false;" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">
        <span class="select2-chosen">CSS</span><abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>   
        <span class="select2-arrow"><b></b></span></a><input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" id="s2id_autogen1"></div>
        <select id="add-essential-requirement" class="requirements-select select2-offscreen" data-placeholder="Add Essential Requirement" tabindex="-1">
            <option></option>
            <option value="cmYiaONlNtw5GP11-e">CAD</option>
            <option value="zdttiUMKAR0sKlSu-e">CSS</option>
            <option value="4MzgJIEyaL2vizhQ-e">Excel Spreadsheets</option>
            <option value="j70U4vt5kWm7wLjB-e">Fireworks</option>
            <option value="7nCu8QIIJQzAQAy3-e">Git</option>
            <option value="1bZM8poaikJRLo5P-e">HTML</option>
        </select>
</div>
<div class="requirement-container sans-serif center"><br><br>
<div class="each-requirement overflow-hidden" data-id="new">
    <div style="margin-left:80px" class="name float-left" data-id="zdttiUMKAR0sKlSu-e">CSS</div>
    <span style="margin-left:-37px;" id="skill-level-0" class="skill-level color-blue center sans-serif">Beginner</span>
    <div style="margin: 20px auto 0" class="slide ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="slider-0" aria-disabled="false">
        <div class="inner-slider-marker"></div>
        <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 0%;"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('change', '.requirements-select', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);

    var name = $this.select2('data').text;
    var str = $this.val();

    $('.initial-r-load').remove();
    $this.parents('.dashboard-requirement-toolbar').siblings('.requirement-container').append('<div class="each-requirement overflow-hidden" data-id="new"></div>');
    $this.parents('.dashboard-requirement-toolbar').siblings('.requirement-container').children('.each-requirement:last').addSlide(name, str);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: base_url + "job/add_requirement",
        dataType: "text",
        data: {
            skl_name: name,
            skl_str: str,
            j_str: window.location.pathname.split('/').pop()
        },
        cache:false,
        success: 
        function(data){
            var response = data;
            /* THIS WORKS */ $this.parents('.dashboard-requirement-toolbar').siblings('.requirement-container').children('.each-requirement:last').html(response)
            /* THIS DOESN'T WORK */ $this.parents('.dashboard-requirement-toolbar').siblings('.requirement-container').children('.each-requirement:last').data('id', response)          
        }
    });

    return false;

});
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How do you check that is doesn't work? `data` method does not set or change the attribute value, it amends the internal data structure.

Comment: @VisioN Usually I'm able to clarify whether it's worked or not by simply looking at the changed `data-id="whatever-value"` in HTML on Dev Tools. Is there another way?

Comment: If you need a markup change then use `.attr('data-id', 'whatever-value')` instead. Otherwise use `.data()` but check the correctness with picking up the value back, i.e. `console.log(el.data('id'))`.

Comment: @VisioN I'm such an idiot at times. Thanks that fixed it. Do you want to create a quick answer and I'll accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just copying the comments, `data` method does not set or change the attribute value, it amends the internal data structure of the element, which is *not displayed* as changed `data-*` attribute.

So, if you need a markup change then use `.attr('data-id', 'whatever-value')` instead. Otherwise use `.data()` method, as you do, but check the correctness with picking up the value back, i.e. `console.log(el.data('id'))`.

**P.S.:** As a side note, I'd recommend you to use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method instead of `parents()`. It will rapidly pick up the first matched parent element, instead of selecting all matched parent elements.

Comment: Also thanks for the tip, I'll be using `closest()` more often.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify code with the following :

```
$this.parents('.dashboard-requirement-toolbar')
     .siblings('.requirement-container')
     .children('.each-requirement:last')
     .attr('data-id', response)
```

This should work.